# Convert American number to European format with numbervalue in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, format

On Excel, I have a column with numbers in American format (ex : 1.536962890625000000e+03) and I want to realize a VBA macro to put them in the European format (ex: 1,536962890625000000e+03).

Usually, I simply use the replace wizard in Excel to replace "." with "," but this time I have a lot of data to proceed and I want to use a VBA macro.

However, when I use the the replace method with a VBA macro, I think it does not consider the digits after the punctuation as decimals because I get huge numbers (ex : 1,53696289062500E+21).

After some digging, I have found the **NumberValue** formula that should do the trick and I want to use it in my macro.

Is there an easy/elegant way to "convert" the American numbers in my column in European ones ?

Comment: I have not been clear, what I call American format are not date but numbers with "." as decimal separator and "," for spacing

Comment: no problem, meanwhile I will try the good old-fashioned way with for/while instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for method looks effective for me

```
Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim n As Integer

        For n = 2 To lrow
        v = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(n, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(n, 1) = v
        Next n
```

Comment: No need for NumberValue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it for the workbook, and have the values retain their numeric characteristics:

```
With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = ","
    .ThousandsSeparator = "."
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the decimal separator in Options:

[image]

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but the file will be used by other people, therefore I rather prefer to convert it properly